# How and Why Would a Species Evolve This Hand Structure

Tags: science-based, creature-design, evolution, humanoid

I have a mental image of a humanoid species with hands possessing three fingers and two thumbs, on opposite sides of the hand:

[image: hand with two opposing thumbs]

*note: it could be animalistic or reptilian, it doesn’t need to be exactly humanoid.

-What creatures would this species evolve from?

-Why would that species have evolved this design?

Comment: You need to restrict yourself to  one question at a time or you risk being closed, also perhaps too broad & opinion based as currently presented, check out the sites rules.

Comment: linked to question https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/21418/how-would-a-two-thumbed-hand-work#comment95421_21418 but this question asks about its evolution.

Comment: @A.I.Breveleri : Nice find, not a duplicate question as such but isn't there answers to everything Capillary is asking in there?

Comment: Hi & welcome! Some brilliant ideas in here, but do take note: although we appreciate and encourage creativity, which is why we're all here!, Stack Exchange is all about ***asking a single focused query and getting viable, on point answers in return***.  If you check out the [tour] and [help], you should get a better idea why your query was closed. It's not because it's bad or anything, it just needs to be broken down into multiple queries and edited to conform to the Rules. Once that's done, it'll likely be reopened!

Comment: After the edit he first answer to the linked question seems to answer the remaining questions. Specifically it answers the why, getting omni- or bidirectional grip for catching fish or climbing trees in odd orientations while feeding. While the first question is not really interesting. Anything can evolve this if it feeds itself in a manner that benefits from it.

Answer (score 2):

A group of people gets a stable form of functional polydactyly (1). Combined with evolutionary pressures to do more complicated stuff with your hands it would mean this genetic abnormality would more often happen until the people without it are considered the mutants who reverted a part of their evolution.

(1): https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.sciencealert.com/a-sixth-finger-on-our-hands-would-actually-be-super-useful

Comment: The link is about a different hand structure with different number of fingers. 1+5 vs 1+3+1. Polydactyly vs zygodactyly.

Answer (score 2):

I'd risk saying tree dwellers, maybe some type of theropod before the loss of 2 of its fingers. You see, this design could be considered  as zygodactyl as seen in these images:

[image]

[image]

Note that the external toe of the owl can swivel to switch between a zygodactyl foot for perching and a "eagle" foot for grabbing prey.

Now, why is this beneficial? The fact that it's common in tree-clinging birds should say enough: it's a great design for climbing and perching. So your hand could perhaps appear in a 5 digit reptilian that went somewhat along the theropod evolutionary path, eventually becorming a feathered creature with traits more found in tree-dwelling primates, maybe backed by a tail for additional support and improved balance. This hand would help it climb trees with ease and wrap its hands around branches, and would likely have sharp claws at the end of each finger. This path wouldn't be too different from ours, as our own opposing digit comes from our tree dwelling ancestors, except yours might also be able to have more controlled descends, going down trees head first due to having backwards facing claws, a trait which would stick around even after they left the trees.

Answer (score 0):

This hand arrangement could evolve from an intelligent creature whose hands had 2 fingers and a thumb that develop on the ulnar side. Then, a mutation might give the species an advantage over other species, but also causes ulnar dimelia.