# What kind of human music do badger-folk like?

Tags: culture, hard-science, music, chimera-folk

Okay, so now that we've established that the [badger folk](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/20335/how-to-justify-digging-claws-and-opposable-thumbs-in-the-same-being) (or *Melinae  sapien*, if you want to be politically correct) are trading their ore to the humans for [cat food](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/30054/8914). Now we need to determine what kind of culture exchange they'll have.

To look at one particular issue, what kind of human music would badger folk prefer? Of course, individual badger folk will have different preferences, but in a similar way that Americans liked British Rock best back in the day, badger folk will like a specific type of human music best.

We can assume that badger folk have similar [musical preferences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zoomusicology) to that of real badgers.

(Note: If you are questioning the [hard-science](/questions/tagged/hard-science) tag, see [Can hard-science apply to social sciences and other academic fields?](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2348/can-hard-science-apply-to-social-sciences-and-other-academic-fields) and [Is the use of the [Hard-Science] tag acceptable in questions with a non-hard premise?](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2761/is-the-use-of-the-hard-science-tag-acceptable-in-questions-with-a-non-hard-pre))

(Note: This isn't opinion based. I'm asking for [hard-science](/questions/tagged/hard-science) answers based on zoomusicology (or other fields), not opinion based-answers.)

Comment: Badger-folk tag is too localized, but [tag:chimera-folk] covers everything that doesn't deserve its own like mer-folk and centaurs.

Comment: To those that are voting to close, please include some discussion in the comments as to why you believe it should be closed.  I have some guesses, but I have a feeling this may be contentious enough to warrant discussion rather than drive-by closes.

Comment: Honestly, I think assuming they'd have similar tastes as real badgers would almost certainly be false. The commonality with humans would actually be larger than with badgers, if we assume that they are capable of verbal communication compatible with humans. And your previous questions seem to assume they can talk with humans?

Comment: @Cort Ammon I guess some people believe seriousness and silliness are mutually exclusive.

Comment: @VilleNiemi Well, it should at least be influenced by their badger nature.

Comment: This is more of a meta question, but I wonder if, for some people, hard-science implies there is only one answer, the answer you get by looking up equations.  If so, it would be a very limited reading of what science is, but it would explain why starting from silliness is unacceptable.

Comment: Related to @VilleNiemi 's comment, do we assume they can talk to humans, or just that they are capable of communicating with them (through one means or another)?  In the case of vocal music, that distinction could be very important.

Comment: @CortAmmon I suppose they can understand human speech, but are basically incapable of speaking it (same for humans with badger speak).

Comment: But they'd still use a vocal language with similar complexity to human languages to communicate with each other?

Comment: First, just because something is tagged [hard-science] doesn't inherently make it not opinion-based. Second, you appear to be assuming all the _Melinae sapien_ have the same musical tastes. If they do, then you can decide on anything you want. If they don't, then the answer is trivial: all of them.

Comment: It *is* possible find related scientific publications - e.g. relative pitch perception in ferrets (another mustelid): http://scitation.aip.org/content/asa/journal/jasa/127/3/10.1121/1.3290988 - although with chimeric folk, you can always import abilities and cultural influences from the fantasy human side.

Comment: @NeilSlater You could incoporate that research into an answer.

Comment: First of all, I am amused and flattered to have inspired follow-ups to my questions.  That said, at least on Cobaltduckworld, the badger-folk *do not* like human music.  They consent to trade and diplomacy out of necessity, but otherwise keep to their own.  Humans smell weird and those things they strum and blow into produce such a horrendous screeching.  I can't stand it!  Argh!!!

Comment: @pyrulez: The reason this is [opinion based] is because if you replace the word 'badger' in the question with the word 'human' you can't get a non-opinion based answer despite there being a wealth of research papers on not only human hearing, but also neurological and physiological effects of various kinds of music. If you move the problem to badgers, where even less is known, it doesn't remove the opinion part of the question..

Comment: It seems to me that one could answer this in a generalized format by looking at 1) the frequencies badgers hear at, and 2) changes to hearing in mammals for creatures that primarily live underground.  At the very least, there should be a potential hard-science answer for what human music badgers will *not* like.

Comment: @cobaltduck Oh, sorry cobaltduck. (Maybe like Rock music, most badger-folk dislike human music, but young badgers do, to the annoyance of their parents).

Comment: @DanSmolinske Yeah, that would probably make a good answer as well.

Comment: @cobaltduck (Also, sorry for any other factual errors relating to badger folk implied in my question.)

Comment: @PyRulez:  I repeat that I am flattered to have inspired you.  Evolution took some very strange turns on Cobaltduckworld.  That it seems to have taken slightly similar turns on Pyrulesworld is interesting.  It doesn't mean they are identical though, nor should they be.  To me, the concept of WorldBuilding is about taking fantastic ideas and having some fun with it.  Let's continue that fun!

Comment: Obviously death metal

Comment: Don't you mean "what kind of music do badger folk _dig_?"

Comment: Google "badger badger" and the answer will be revealed.

Answer (score 6):

Let's approach it the way we can (generalize) human music.  I can find nothing on badger behavior towards music, so this is all just speculation.  Also, badger humans don't exist (yet?).

**Dwellings**

Badgers live in underground dwelling units that are tightly knit.  This could suggest a large interest in community and cooperation in tough times and good.  This could also suggest a little bit less on the bass, because you'd be shaking dirt all over the place.

**Diet**

Diet of a badger is largely known to eat bugs to small mammals.  This helps me in no way.

**Precedents**

[Mr. Badger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Wind_in_the_Willows#Main_characters) was a grumpy, but wise character who pointed out the realities of the world to an arguably naive character in the Wind in the Willows.

**Geography**

Badgers are primarily found in North America, Britain, and Ireland, but can be found in many other places.

**Society**

I am guessing that Badger-People might feel marginalized from both human and badger populations.

From those five generalizations, I would put their favorite to be **Alt-Country**.

Brit/US Indie [Geography] music with a realist, sometimes sad slant [Mr Badger]; a bit of alternative feel [Society], a hint of bluegrass [Diet], a social component [Dwelling], and not too much bass [underground Dwelling].

While it is not my favorite music, but I'd call it [Indie/Alt/Country/Bluegrass](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=braQeLkJUvE).  That is broad speculation.

Comment: Technically they aren't badger humans. It's a case of convergent evolution. (Don't worry though; badger folk accidently call us monkey badgers sometimes as well.)

Comment: @PyRulez - okay, well I kind of still stick by my answer..  I think they'd like that music video, based on their inherited nature.

Answer (score 6):

I will start by adding a link to the audio frequency ranges of some [animals](http://www.lsu.edu/deafness/HearingRange.html) . Although the badger is not present in the list provided at the bottom of the above link , a ferrets frequency range is provided. Since the badger is closely related to a [ferret](http://a-z-animals.com/animals/badger/) , we can assume that the badgers audio frequency lies between 16 and 44,000 Hz. A human beings range is 64-23,000 Hz.

So a badger can pick up on wider spectrum of frequencies than humans. Most music genres humans enjoy or recognise fall into the audio spectrum they can identify , so it is probable that badgers will enjoy the same , also you might invent a new genre that falls into the badgers spectrum.

As far as the question is concerned , with their level of sophistication it would be unfair to generalise a particular genre for the whole species. They might not be huge fans of music that may that may hamper their burrows which is completely logical.

My guess is they will invent new genres like humans did , I guess this too is a part of evolving.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question, "What kind of human music do badger-folk like?"

Answer (score 4):

I would expect that any music with synthetically added room effects would be very bothersome for them.  Living in tunnels, they would be quickly aware of what sounds carry through a tunnel and which ones do not.  Our human tendency to "just add some reverb" to make it sound better would be appalling to them in the same way it hurts the eye to see a really garish green and red image, or the feeling of fingernails down a chalk board.  Most modern pop would be impossible to listen to (for the badgers I mean...)

The real badger is a solitary creature, which would certainly have an effect on the kind of music they like.  I think it could have any one of a number of effects, but I'd peg the most likely to be a preference for music with many instruments playing together, as such music might be a symbol differentiating them from their solitary lesser kin.

Between these, I would say classical orchestral music would be most preferable to them.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing the badgerfolk don't natively speak the human language?  They probably don't get much out of lyrics, then.

They may not even be able to read human emotions.  A human might think a song was "sad" or "melancholy", but a badger might not recognize that those intonations mean sadness.

Badgerfolk probably prefer instrumental music (or classical music, as AndreiROM said), because that music is designed to be interesting even without lyrics.

---

I'm unsure if the music trade is possible, though.  Checking your other questions, this is a fantasy world, and the technology level is "early 1800s".  The phonograph wasn't invented until 1877, and even after that it would take several years for the technology to be widespread enough to make music for trade.

If badgerfolk like human music, the way they listen to it is the way everyone else does at that time: they go find a tavern, buy a drink, and listen to whatever the bard wants to sing.

Answer (score 1):

> what kind of human music would badger folk prefer

They would like music that they could sing themselves and join in with. If you listen to these badger vocalisations - https://youtu.be/b4lpFjHsGLo
- you will realised they have high-pitched voices so songs by the Chipmunks would be suitable https://youtu.be/-RP19fnff_c

Or

They would be fascinated by human music that seemed at least superficially to be about badgers:

1. The White Stripes

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_White_Stripes

---

2. Ebony and Ivory by Paul McCartney and Stevie Wonder

https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=ebony+and+ivory

---

3. Badger badger badger by Brian May

https://youtu.be/EllYgcWmcAY

Answer (score 0):

This is what envision when I think "what music would play in the town square of a badger folk village?"
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8bzziAv9o4w

Comment: This does not meet the requirements of the [tag:hard-science] tag.