# How human-like can a badger sound?

Tags: language, interspecies-relations, chimera-folk

Okay, so now some [badger folk](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/20335/how-to-justify-digging-claws-and-opposable-thumbs-in-the-same-being) want to try and imitate human speech. How close can badger vocal cords emulate human speech? I know dogs can crudely imitate human speech (we can see [two dogs with the ability to hold conversations in English](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4S-N7xWWrbo)). I don't know how good badgers at are this task though?

(Even if it isn't very good, this skill could be at least be used for parodying the [stupid humans trying to sell music to badgerland](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/30107/what-kind-of-human-music-do-badger-folk-like), like [these Italians making fun of English](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_g6YxkSqL20))

Comment: I'm pretty sure that no studies have been undertaken to determine how human like badgers might sound if they learned English.

Seeing how this question will probably generate only opinion-based answers, I think you should assume that badgers will be able to make themselves understood to humans, even if only with "great difficulty". That degree of difficulty will be up to you to decide.

Comment: As a non-native English speaker, I am not surprised at all by knowing that two dogs can hold a conversation in that language. What still puzzless me is that, apparently, two humans can hold a conversation in English, too! :-p

Comment: How would you judge how close a sound is to a human's? It seems a bit subjective.

Answer (score 4):

They are badger-**folk**,  not badgers. What makes them anthropomorphic? That will include bipedalism, hands, expressive faces, and vocal apparatus.  Anything that is different from the stock anthrpomorphic animal needs to be described directly in the story.

Just have them talk. People will not have problems with it.  Any differences affecting human speech interoperability is arbitrary stuff you can make up.  Homonids are different from lemeers for example, and developing the speech apparatus was part of making "primate-folk".  But it could have turned out differently.

Comment: I wasn't saying they couldn't talk. I was just saying they would sound different.

Comment: Yes, but don't ask us how different.  You get to make it up.